# Getting non-initial argument User input in a java program from command prompt

Tags: java, command, java.util.scanner

I am writing a program that must be run through the command line. It has initial input as an argument(`java filename arg arg arg`), but then requires more information to be entered later. I tried using a basic scanner and `.nextLine()` but the strings would never actually be picked up by the scanner and hitting enter would just move me to the next line.

Can I use a scanner for this or do I have to use something different?

**Edit:** here is the section of code I'm using(Please note I did also import the correct library):

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean cont = true;
    while(cont)
    {
        int indx;
        System.out.print("Enter input: ");
        String searched = in.nextLine();
        if(searched.equals("esc"))
        {
            cont = false;
            continue;
        }
        else
            indx = binSearch(sorted,searched);
        if(indx != -1)
            System.out.println("'" + searched + "'" +
                               " was found at index: " +
                               indx);
        else
            System.out.println("'" + searched + "'" +
                               "was not found");
    }
    in.close();

    }
```

**Edit 2**: changed the `==` comparison of 2 strings to `.equals`

**Edit 3**: Added the binSearch Method I am using:

```
    public static int binSearch(String[] A, String word)
    { 
    int i = 0; int j = A.length; int m;
    while( i < j )
    {
            m = (i + j)/2;//find centerpoint
            if(cSL(word,A[m]))
                    j = m;//move right side up
            else i = m;//move left side up
    }
    if(A[i].equalsIgnoreCase(word)) return i;
    else if(A[j].equalsIgnoreCase(word)) return j;
    else return -1;
    }
```

**Edit 4: So I guess it must be UNIX, everything works in cmd.**

Comment: yes, you can use a scanner for this goal

Comment: yes, but would you please show us your code so we could help more.

Comment: @Leah I added in the code I'm using that is related to the problem.

Comment: Not the correct way to compare strings for equality. Search "how to compare strings in java" - it gets asked 15 times a day.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yeah sorry about that I had to retype the code from another computer and just got mixed up. I have an `else' after that that would trigger another event, and that event has not triggered so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Please add the `else` so the example represents the actual. You'll get better answers quicker that way.

Comment: So copying your code and running it with an added `else` which simply prints a a few words works as I would expect. The `else` is triggered if I enter "esc" or not.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I added in the rest of the code related to this section. The method I use just runs A binary search on an array I made earlier in the program and returns an integer depending on the index of the second argument and returns -1 if it is not found.

Comment: @Ben do you have a line somewhere in your code like `int indx=0;`

Comment: @Leah Yeah, I defined all my variables at the top of the program. I'll add it in in case it confuses others though.

Comment: It works for me that way too. It might be best for you to make a simple test program and start with the control structure of this and add the pieces to it. That way you'll immediately know what's causing the problem.

Comment: I also tested it and it works for me, too. Do you get an exception maybe or what output do you get? Are you sure that the binSearch works as it should?

Comment: @Leah Im pretty sure that the method should be working, even if it isn't returning the correctly. I added it just in case.

Comment: So I'm not sure if this is something I should have mentioned earlier but I'm using UNIX to run this program and not command prompt. It should have all of the same properties and commands. I just tried what @ChiefTwoPencils suggested and I got a basic program to work in the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare Strings with the .equals method. This must be the problem. Try this way:

```
if(searched.equals("esc")) {
        cont = false;
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't solve the problem. I would have had to fix that down the line though.

Comment: down the line you mean that there are other ifs in which you haven't changed? in fact this is the way you can compare strings. otherways it will not work.

Comment: I said down the line meaning I would have changed it later once I realized it wasn't working. It was the only comparison of strings I have